# Insert faces hotkey in the latest blender

Tags: faces

I am following the donut tutorial level 3 part 2. In the video he says that when you press I it will insert faces. But when I do that a insert keyframe menu pops up? Do you know how I can insert faces?

I am in object mode and this is how it looks
[image]

Thanks for your help in advanced.

Comment: Press F to _insert_ (make) a face - use "I" to _inset_ a face. Also, you must be in _Edit Mode_ for these to work - in _Object Mode_, "I" will insert keyframes.

Comment: Are you in *Edit* mode? In *Object* mode is `I` is the shortcut for keyframes. Also, make sure your mouse pointer is in the 3D viewport.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answers. I am in object mode and it is still the insert keyframe menu that pops up. I have uploaded a picture of how it looks.

Comment: A summary of both comments: Select the object, switch into edit mode (tab), select the edges you wanna connect, then press F.

Comment: Thanks! It solved it!